# Automation between two Excel spreadsheets (Inserting data from one to another)

Tags: excel, automation

What I want to do is create automation that will copy data from ROW1 on one excel file and insert it to ROW 1 on another excel file that already contains data, and shift all other rows down (new data always on top).

Comment: Macro ran from the origin file or the destination file?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
dim wbkDest as workbook, wbkOrg as workbook

'assumes both workbooks are open
set wbkDest=workbooks("DestWorkbook.xlsx") 'update this
set wbkOrg=workbooks("OriginWorkbook.xlsx") 'update this

wbkdest.sheets(1).rows(1).insert
wbkorg.sheets(1).rows(1).copy wbkdest.sheets(1).cells(1,1)
```

Comment: This is a good start, I assume the automation for opening the worksheets is not complicated.

Comment: not really: `set wbkDest=workbooks("c:\mypath\DestWorkbook.xlsx").open`